# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}^* \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2^{k-2}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

In order to compute the value of the Carmichael function for $2^k$ with $k > 2$, my notes indicate that one has to stablish that $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}^* \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2^{k-2}}$ .

However, I have not been able to find this theorem in the bibliography (essentially  Shoup's number theory), nor googling nor on stack exchange.

Does anyone know  proof of this fact?

**Edit**

Here is a python script for the powers I was asked to compute:

```
for i in range(3,40):
    find = True
    for j in range(1,280):
        if(5**j % 2**i == 1 and find == True):
            find = False
            print(2**i," has finished with ", j)
```

and here the results:

```
8  has finished with  2
16  has finished with  4
32  has finished with  8
64  has finished with  16
128  has finished with  32
256  has finished with  64
512  has finished with  128
1024  has finished with  256
```

So experimentally, it seems that $ord(5) = 2^{k-2}$ for $k > 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: compute the order of $5$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/(2^k))^{\times}$.

Edit: I was asked to be more specific. 
I suggest that you prove that $2^k$ does not divide $5^{2^{k-3}}-1$ but divides $5^{2^{k-2}}-1$. Thus, you can deduce that $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}/(2) \times \mathbb{Z}/(2^{k-2}) \rightarrow (-1)^x5^y \in (\mathbb{Z}/(2^k))^{\times}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Is this using the classification group of finite abelian groups?

Comment: No. Just elementary number theory and basic finite group theory.

Comment: To be honest I'm a bit lost. Could you provide some extra information?